# Running program in a random minute of an interval

Tags: java, time, cron, automation

I'm looking for an instrument, that could help me to solve the subject problem. 
I have an interval (say, an hour. 8 to 9). And I need to run a (java) program in a random minute in it. 
Cron looks like a proper tool, but I see no random function. I'm quite sure there's an instrument that smart people are using for this, so I'd like to learn it during this training project development. 
I'm also want to know, which one is better production practice: writing a custom schedule via (for example) ScheduledExecutorService or using external tools like cron?

Comment: do you mind schedule it using Cron while doing the random thing in Java?

Comment: No, I want to schedule it somewhere to run a program once a day in random time from an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
00 8 * * * sleep $[RANDOM\%90]m; cmdHere
```

That will run once between 8 and 9 after a random delay after 8:00am

Comment: if this works, it's the best solution for me.

Comment: Wow this looks good! Will try it out in the morning. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

crontab syntax to run a script every minute between 8 and 9:

```
* 8 * * * yourscript.sh
```

To execute it just once within the hour:

```
0 8 * * * yourscript.sh
```

This will always start it at 8:00. I think I understand better your question but I don't understand why it has to be at a random time and I don't think this is possible in cron.
You can start your java main method with following section:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int waitTime=new Random().nextInt(60);
    Thread.sleep(waitTime*60*1000); // sleep expects milliseconds
    // continue real main implementation
}
```

Comment: This would run it at a random time every minute between 8 and 9. I think the OP wants to run it once between 8 and 9.

Comment: aa333, you're right. That's just what I need.
Conffusion, I'm sorry if I didn't explained it right.